# How to validate the API called was from website only?

Tags: php, rest, phalcon

I created some APIs i want to validate those APIs.
for Example :

```
http://www.domain.in/tool/api/add
post : {data}
```

i need to give the response, if its called from website only.
how can i do this in phalcon ?

Comment: can you show us what you've tried so far?  Currently, your question is far too broad for anyone to give you a succinct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the Referer in the HTTP header. Note that Referer is fairly easy to spoof.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "website_url_here") {
    //respond
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
}
```